# Curl request from cron job is not working,but works manually

Tags: cron, scripts, curl

I have a cron job that runs every minute and makes a curl request and i have verified that using grep on the syslogs.

But the curl is not happening somehow and moreover i have a small echo statement in the cron that i log in some file.Even that log is not printing but manually when run my shell file it works.

Can someone help me out in this.?

Update :
This is the shell file i am using

```
#This file sends the changed files to our server
#var=$(ls ~/Downloads | grep -v "^d")
#files=""
#for f in $(ls ~/OurDrive | grep -v ^d)
#       do
#               
#               files+="$f"","
#               
#       done 
files=()

cd /home/user/OurDrive
for file in *; do
    [[ -d $file ]] && continue
    files+=( "$file" )
done


comma_separated=$(IFS=,; echo "${files[*]}")
echo "$comma_separated" 
curl --data "file_list=$comma_separated&username=${USER}" http://localhost:8084/url/add.do
echo "done"> /home/user/Desktop/log.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) and explicitly use bash (on Ubuntu /bin/sh links to [dash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
```

The first will search the environment for `bash`.

Comment: `/bin/sh` links to `dash`? How come?

Comment: @Jobin Click the link labeled [dash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh).